# How to mark java private methods used in deprecated API

Tags: java, coding-style

How to mark java private methods used in deprecated API, so it will be clear, that they exist only because deprecated API is not removed it and should not be used in new class' API?

like this

```
@Deprecated
    public void doSomething() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(returnList());
    }

    private List<String> returnList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

I was thinking of adding

```
//TODO remove this after #deprecatedMethod is removed
```

But I am not sure it is accurate

Comment: Coud you elaborate you question more clearly with some codes?

Answer (score 3):

To mark methods that shouldn't be used, you can declare methods itself as `@Deprecated`, to add comments best practice is clarify in `javadoc` field. I would suggest also to create new methods and link them in javadoc to avoid future problems:

```
/**
 * This method use a deprecated API
 *
 * @deprecated use {@link #newMethodNodeprecated()} instead.  
 */
@Deprecated
public void oldMethod() {
// ...
}
```

Comment: I think he means how to mark private methods as not be reused by any new methods implemented.

Answer (score 1):

A `private` method is never exposed in the API, so there should be no reason to mark them, as the user of the API will have no knowledge about them.

Also, if you are using any IDE, a private method that is not used will be highlighted as `method is never used`.